# Take a screenshot of an area covered by an UIImageView object

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am trying to take a screenshot of an area covered by a UIImageview object. I have overlaid the image with some UILabel objects and want to save the shot of just the area

I have tried

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

but it is giving my a shot of the whole screen

I have also tried

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageHolder.frame.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

That is giving me a rectangle of the top half of the screen

Comment: Did you add the `UILabel` as subviews of the image view?

Comment: yes i did. otherwise it wouldnt compile

Comment: Perfect, you can see my answer below on how to render an image from a `UIImageView` and its subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view.drawHierachy actually accept the boundary as bounds rather than frame
i will assume that image is actually the UIImageView

```
var bounds= CGRect(x: -image.frame.minX,y: -image.frame.minY,width: view.bounds.size.width,height: view.bounds.size.height)

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.frame.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let outputImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: you just saved me

Answer (score 2):

If you add the `UILabel` as a subview to the `UIImageView` you can use an extension function like this to capture an image context of the image view and its subviews (the labels).

```
extension UIImageView {

    func renderSubviewsToImage() -> UIImage? {

        guard let image = image else { return nil }

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        self.layer.render(in: context)

        let renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return renderedImage

    }

}
```